# How to disable swipe gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have swipe gesture

```
@IBAction func rightSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

I want to temporarily disable this swipe using long press.

```
@IBAction func LongPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `yourSwipeGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false`